# Convert a Flag Enum to another Flag Enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have two Flag enums that look something like the following

```
[Flags]
public enum EnumTypeOne: ulong
{
    NONE                    = 0,
    STUFF_ONE               = ( 1 << 0 ),
    STUFF_TWO               = ( 1 << 1 )
}

[Flags]
public enum EnumTypeTwo: ulong
{
    NONE                    = 0,
    STUFF_ONE               = ( 1 << 0 ),
    STUFF_TWO               = ( 1 << 1 )
}
```

One enum is inside one class library(internal use only) and the other will be supplied as dll.

Internally I would like to marshall between these two enums since they are identical. I know how to do this with a regular enum however it does not seem to work if more than one flag is set on one of the enums.

I have tried using the following solution

```
var enumResult = (EnumTypeOne)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumTypeOne), Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumTypeTwo), mEnumTypeTwo);
```

As stated above this only works if only a single flag is in use, the use of multiple flags calls it to fall over.

Is there a solution to allow me to convert between the two enums efficiently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just cast it

```
EnumTypeOne a = EnumTypeOne.STUFF_ONE|EnumTypeOne.STUFF_TWO;
EnumTypeTwo b = (EnumTypeTwo)a;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think it would be this simple!

Comment: @const_ref: enums are just integers underneath, so if the values mean the same thing, it's safe to just convert between them as is.

Comment: @siride I understood that this was a ulong underneath the hood, but   I had had difficulty in the past when converting enums to enums and really didnt think it would be this simple. Cheers